# How to provide a name attribute in Formcontrol react-bootstrap?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I need to provide the name attribute to access it in backend. How to write the name attribute in Formcontrol tag of react-bootstrap.

Comment: Can you share the code which you have tried?

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's working fine. I just did
<FormControl type="email" placeholder="Enter email address" ref="loginemail" name="email" />